# jQuery autocomplete frozen for initial few alphabets

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Below is the snippet which add an autocomplete suggestion to html input box holding the name of cities for a particular delivery purpose:

```
getAllActiveCitiesList: function(){
    js_script.script.cities_polling_count += 1;
    js_script.script.ajax_loading_message = "Fetching all active and approved citiess....give us a minute!"
    if(js_script.script.all_active_approved_citiess == null && js_script.script.cities_polling_count < 12){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "some/url/to/fetch/data",
            success: function(data){
                js_script.script.cities_polling_count = 0;
                if(data.length > 0){
                    js_script.script.all_active_approved_citiess =  data;
                    for(index in data){
                        cities_data = data[index]
                        js_script.script.cities_to_id_map[cities_data["name"] +" ( "+cities_data["citiesId"]+" )"] = cities_data["id"];
                    }
                    // setup autocomplete
                    $("#mss_cities_id").autocomplete({
                       source: Object.keys(js_script.script.cities_to_id_map)
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                js_script.script.flashPageBanner("<strong>Warning:</strong> Something went wrong with backend, auto-suggest for Citiess might not work ");
            }
        });
    }else if(js_script.script.cities_polling_count % 12 == 0){
        js_script.script.flashPageBanner("Something is wrong, auto-suggest for Citiess might not work ");
    }
}
```

Markup where this is assigned

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 no-padding-left">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-lg-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="mss_cities_id" placeholder="Cities ID">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default refresh-cities-id custom-hover-tooltip" title="Refresh Citiess List - Use ONLY if something is wrong!!">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax response send a city data which contains both city names as well as city codes.

So far so good, `ajax` sets around 5000 values in autocomplete. My problem is that if we type slowly one or two alphabets the whole page is stucked in *frozen* mode and `chrome` sometimes would suggest to kill the page.

If we type quickly, generally no issue comes. My end users are people with slow typing skills and this *feature* is becoming more of a problem for them than solution.

One solution that comes to my mind is to stop the autocomplete lookup until, say, 4 characters are typed but this might fail the purpose as some of the cities (city codes) might have just 2 alphabets. Please suggest how can this problem be solved?

jquery version is 1.12.4

Comment: You can try with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990730/3085279

Comment: You may benefit from adding a debouncer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript

Comment: @TanDuong : thats same as putting `minimum character` length in autocomplete search!